# The value of parameter a for which $\frac{ax^2+3x−4}{a+3x−4x^2}$ takes all real values for $x\in \mathbb R$ are:

Tags: maxima-minima

I solve it and get the answer $a\in [1,7]$.but my teacher told me to take the verification of the boundary values of a.because at the boundary values, $ax^2+3x-4$ and $3x-4x^2+a$ have common roots.so,its obvious that value of a will not count in the answer.But my question is,is it necessary to have common roots between $ax^2+3x-4$ and $3x-4x^2+a$ at only boundary values.if yes then why??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If both roots are common then $a=-4$ // if only one root is common, assume it to be $\alpha$ then solve for $a$ and check